# Вставка HTML в атрибут

Tags: angular2

Необходимо вставить HTML код символа в атрибут тега. Делаю `attr.data-test="{{myVar}}"` на выходе получаю в этом атрибуте код, который  полностью выводится на странице как текст, а не символ, то есть не рендерится. Как сделать чтоб он выводил там символ, а не код символа?

Comment: То есть, вы, используете, какой-то шаблонизатор, но умалчиваете об этом?

Comment: @And в тегах написано angular2, если вы знакомы с ним, у вас такого вопроса не должно возникать.

Comment: является mvc. А вот символы вставляющиеся в html начинаются с символа &. Вопрос не совсем понятен, и не тегов, а меток.

Comment: @And код символа отображается как код символа, а не как символ. Если в ручную прописать в атрибуте код символа, то в коде он выглядит как символ, а если подставить код символа из переменной, то он отображается как код символа, а не символ

Comment: Данный символ экранируется по технике безопасности. Советую почитать:  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html - кстати, возможно [innerHTML] - форматирование решит проблему, но это не безопасно..

Comment: @And я в курсе что там происходит, вопрос как вывести символ, а не почему так происходит

Comment: @And innerhtml не решит проблему

Comment: Из той же ссылки адаптировано немного:
`constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { this.myVar= sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml("<test></test>") }`;

Comment: @Alexandr наработает . Вместо символа: SafeValue must use [property]=binding:

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/EYL0XnKKmkPRBbWWsYzI?p=preview

Comment: В общем, у вас другая проблема. Решение: http://plnkr.co/edit/1a7BRJNglzY5WKq6Q48w?p=preview
Взято отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript
Я могу поподробнее объяснить, только оформите свой вопрос чтобы он был с примером кода.

Comment: @Alexandr за пример спасибо! Ссылка на планкер, почему-то не прикрепляется